# WPF adapt Childrens Control Width and Height to parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a group of radio buttons that i use to select different viewmodes.
The Radiobutts have an additional geometry property so they can contain a path.
What i want to change is its resize behaviour.

if i resize the window vertically, they resize the way i want them to.

but if i resize the window horizontally, the stackpanel in which the buttons are inside of, will just exceed the window size instead of resizing its children.
does anyone see where i messed this up?

Trying to figure it out for way to long now....
[image]

here my xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2"  Name="GrdRbs">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource stdForeGround}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource stdBackGround}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource stdBorder}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="80">
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" ContentSource="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                <Path StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Fill="{StaticResource stdDisabled}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="{TemplateBinding IconPath}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource stdMouseOver}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource stdBlue}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=GrdRbs}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="stlViewModeSelection">
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Default" x:Name="rbViewDefault" IsChecked="True" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 640,0 640,1080 M 1280,0 1280,1080 M 0,360 1920,360 M 0,720 1920,720"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Split Horizontal" x:Name="rbViewSplitHorizontal" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 0,540 1920,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Split Vertical" x:Name="rbViewSplitVertical" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,0 960,1080 "/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Trible Up" x:Name="rbViewTribleUp" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,540 960,1080 M 0,540 1920,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Trible Down" x:Name="rbViewTribleDown" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,0 960,540 M 0,540 1920,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Trible Left" x:Name="rbViewTribleLeft" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,0 960,1080 M 960,540 1920,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Trible Right" x:Name="rbViewTribleRight" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,0 960,1080 M 0,540 960,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Quad" x:Name="rbViewQuad" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 960,0 960,1080 M 0,560 1920,560"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="HMode" x:Name="rbViewHMode" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0 M 640,0 640,1080 M 1280,0 1280,1080 M 640,540 1280,540"/>
        <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon GroupName="View" Content="Single" x:Name="rbViewSingle" IconPath="M 0,0 1920,0 1920,1080 0,1080 0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In case anybody wants to built this here is the RadiobuttonWithIcon class:

```
class RadioButtonWithIcon : RadioButton
{   
    public Geometry IconPath
    {
        get { return (Geometry)this.GetValue(IconPathProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(IconPathProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconPath), typeof(Geometry), typeof(RadioButtonWithIcon), new PropertyMetadata(default(Geometry)));   
}
```

Comment: thas is how StackPanel arranges items. change its orientation and you should observe the same behavior affecting height. it considers one dimension infinite

Comment: As @ASh said - that's the way StackPanel works. BTW, behavior you want is probably not implementable - if you want all your buttons to somehow shrink to their minimum size (still keeping all the text visible). But you can achieve similar effect if you make all your buttons of same width. Your can simply put all your buttons into UniformGrid with 10 columns. However, then you'll have to deal with long text (for example, trimming it with ellipsis)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. With your idea i have been able to make it work with a left alligned uniform grid with only one row!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Resolved this by replacing the stackpanel with a uniform grid

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="Default" GroupName="View" Content="Default" x:Name="rbViewDefault" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.Default}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="Single" GroupName="View" Content="Single" x:Name="rbViewSingle"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.Single}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="SplitHorizontal" GroupName="View" Content="Split Horizontal" x:Name="rbViewSplitHorizontal"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.SplitHorizontal}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="SplitVertical" GroupName="View" Content="Split Vertical" x:Name="rbViewSplitVertical"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.SplitVertical}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="TribleTop" GroupName="View" Content="Triple Up" x:Name="rbViewTribleUp"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.TribleTop}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="TribleBottom" GroupName="View" Content="Triple Down" x:Name="rbViewTribleDown"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.TribleBottom}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="TribleLeft" GroupName="View" Content="Triple Left" x:Name="rbViewTribleLeft"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.TribleLeft}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="TribleRight" GroupName="View" Content="Triple Right" x:Name="rbViewTribleRight"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.TribleRight}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="HMode" GroupName="View" Content="HMode" x:Name="rbViewHMode"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.HMode}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="Quad" GroupName="View" Content="Quad" x:Name="rbViewQuad"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.Quad}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="Six" GroupName="View" Content="Six" x:Name="rbViewSix"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.Six}}"/>
    <ctrl:RadioButtonWithIcon ViewMode="Custom" GroupName="View" Content="Custom" x:Name="rbViewCustom"  IsChecked="{Binding SelectedViewMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static view:ViewModes.Custom}}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

Result:

[image]